# Dissipation in hyperbolic and spherical space

Tags: curvature, point-particles, dissipation

Say that we have a point that emits point particles that all travel at the same velocity in a random direction and neither their velocity nor their direction changes and neither does the position of the point emitting said particles. As the emitted particles get further away from the point, they will dissipate in that they will become less frequent per unit of space (in more than one spatial dimension). This means that if the average frequency of detecting an emitted particle at a distance of 1 from the point emitting particles is 1, then it will be detected at the frequency $1/r^{d-1}$ where $r$ is the distance from the point that is emitting particles and $d$ is the amount of spatial dimensions. Now, say that instead of regular euclidean space of dimension $d$ you have hyperbolic or spherical space of dimension $d$ (of course it is more than 1 dimension because the idea of curved space doesn't work in one dimension, and dissipation can hardly be called dissipation due to the frequency being invariant with respect to the distance from the point that is emitting particles), how can we change the equation to take into account the curvature of the space too? (Curvature can be any real number)

Comment: geometrical spreading has nothing to do with dissipation.   the energy is not lost via irreversible mechanisms and the frequency doesn't change.  so the premise of your question is false.  wave propagation in Riemannian geometry is standard textbook stuff.  Have a look at Marcel Berger's book.

Answer (score 1):

## One way to do these calculations explicitly

The volume of an $n$-ball in Euclidean space is $\pi^{n/2}~R^n~/~(n/2)!$ and your assumption about constant flux means that there is a constant number $dQ$ of particles between a ball of radius $R$ and radius $R + dR$, whence we find out that their inverse density in that shell is:$$dV/dQ = n~\pi^{n/2}~R^{n-1}~(dR/dQ)~/~(n/2)!,$$ or defining $\lambda = dQ/dR$ (something like if $u$ particles are expelled per unit time at speed $v$ then $\lambda = u/v$) and $\rho = dQ/dV$ we'd find $\rho = \lambda (n/2)! / (n \pi^{n/2} R^{n-1}).$

## Spherical space problems

In spherical space the geodesics, great circles, eventually loop back on themselves. This has the nasty problem that there is no "steady state" building up due to that constant flux $u$, but the number of particles in the sphere instead goes to infinity. You might be able to fix this by putting a black hole that's destroying particles at the opposite side of the sphere and asking for the gradient.

So that works by using the generalized spherical coordinates for $\mathbb R^n:$ $(r, \theta, \{\phi_i\})$ where $\theta \in [0, 2\pi),\;\phi_i \in [0, \pi),\; i \in \{1,\dots n - 2\},$ with Euclidean $x_k = r~\cos\phi_k~\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \sin\phi_i$ for $k \le n-2$ and $(x_{n-1}, x_n) = (r~\cos\theta, r~\sin\theta)~\cdot~\prod_i \sin\phi_i.$

I believe that the volume element associated with $r$ is still $dr$, but with $\phi_k$ in general it is $r~d\phi_k~\prod_{i<k}\sin\phi_i.$ Defining $d = n - 1$, this means that the integral you need to do is:$$V^\text{sph}_{d}(\psi) = r^{d}~S_{d-1}~\int_0^\psi d\phi~\sin^{d-1}(\phi)$$where $S_{k}$ is the volume of the unit $k$-sphere (AKA the surface area of the unit $k+1$-ball). So for example for the 2-sphere (globe) we start from $S_1 = 2\pi$ (circle circumference!) and this yields $2~\pi~r^2~(1-\cos\psi)$ for the volume of the embedded 2-ball which has radius $r~\psi.$ For the 3-sphere (glome) we would start from $S_2 = 4 \pi$ and this yields $2 \pi r^3 (\psi - \sin\psi\cos\psi).$

Then you would do the above rigamarole with that volume.

## Hyperbolic space

The same problem of definition would not be an issue for a hyperbolic space -- it is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ so it is infinite in all directions.

I believe for this you simply use spherical coordinates for $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ paired with a hyperbolic coordinate, so you have $(\rho, \eta, \theta, \{\phi_k\})$ with the $\theta$ and $\phi_k$ acting exactly as before, except with $r = \rho~\sinh\eta.$ Then at constant $\rho$ we have $V^\text{hyp}_d(u) = \rho^d~S_{d-2}~\int_0^u d\eta~\sinh^{d-2}\eta~\cosh\eta$ or so, leading to something like a $\sinh^{d-1}(u)$ dependence on the $n$-ball radius, which will be something like $\rho~u.$ I am much less clear on the particulars here but I figure it's doable with about a day or two's study.

The major result here is that the volume of the ball in the spherical space hits an eventual constant while the volume of the ball in the hyperbolic space increases exponentially, so in the spherical space you eventually have a return to the infinite density of the emitter while in the hyperbolic the density instead decays to zero exponentially.